# Are determinants functions, numbers or matrices?

Tags: determinant

Let $M$ be a matrix such that
\begin{equation}
M = \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\ 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}
As I understand it, 
\begin{equation}
\det(M) = \begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\ 
\end{vmatrix} = ad-bc =z 
\end{equation}
So, assuming $m_{ij} \in \Bbb{R}$ then $z \in \Bbb{R}$.

But I thought we consider $\begin{vmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\ 
\end{vmatrix}$ a number not a matrix? Apostol mentions "determinant functions". So now I am really confused. Might $\det(M)$ be a "determinant function" acting on $M$?

**My Question: Are determinants matrices, numbers or functions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\det$ is a function from $n \times n$ matrices to numbers.  The determinant of a particular $n \times n$ matrix is a number.

Answer (score 2):

The determinant of any particular matrix is a number; the process of taking a determinant is a *function*, namely, the function which associates to each matrix its determinant.